# Passing Socket.io object between React components

Tags: reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to implement live chat in my React application. This is my first time working with socket.io and I'm having some troubles with it.
I create a new socket and connection in my `App.js` like this:

```
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

  const setupSocket = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if(token != null && !socket) {
      const newSocket = io("http://localhost:5000", {
          query: {
              token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
          },
          transport : ['websocket']
      });

      newSocket.on("disconnect", () => {
        setSocket(null);
        setTimeout(setupSocket, 3000);
      });

      newSocket.on("connect", () => {
      });

      setSocket(newSocket);
    }
  }

  // set the socket whenever the App component loads
  useEffect(() => {
    setupSocket();
  }, []);
```

and pass it from `App.js` to other components like this:

```
return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route path="/login" 
                 render={() => <Login setupSocket={setupSocket}/>} 
                 exact
          />
          <Route path='/chatroom' 
                 render={() => <Chatroom socket={socket} />}
                 exact
          />
          <Route path='/chat/:id' 
                 render={() => <Chat socket={socket}/>}
                 exact
          />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
```

I'm entering the `Chat` component from `Chatroom.js` via the link:

```
<Button href={"/chat/" + String(chatroom._id)} className={classes.button} variant="contained" color="primary"> Join </Button>
```

And when I try to access the socket in `Chat.js`, `socket` is `null`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import {withRouter, useLocation} from "react-router-dom";

const Chat = ({match, socket}) => {

    const chatroomId = match.params.id;
    

    useEffect(() => {   
        console.log("Chat ID: ", chatroomId);
        console.log("Socket: ", socket);
       
        socket.emit("joinRoom", {
            chatroomId,
        });

        return () => {
            socket.emit("leaveRoom", {
                chatroomId,
            })
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div >
            CHAT
        </div>
    );
}

export default Chat;
```

Do you know what am I doing wrong? I tried to pass `socket` via the line from `Chatroom.js` along with `chatroom._id`, but learned it's impossible to pass an object that way. I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use context api to share the socket between various components instead of passing in router?

Context file

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://localhost:3000'),
  SocketContext = createContext<Socket>(socket);

socket.on('connect', () => console.log('connected to socket'));

const SocketProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
  return (
    <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>{children}</SocketContext.Provider>
  );
};
export { SocketContext, SocketProvider };
```

then in App.jsx, like this

```
import { SocketProvider } from './context/socket';

//
return {
 <SocketProvider>
// other components
    </SocketProvider>
}
```

After that you can use socket in any child component with useContext hook like this -

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { SocketContext } from '../context/socket';

const Sample = () => {
  const socket = useContext(SocketContext);
```

Comment: Thank you! I'd really appreciate that! I will read about context API as I haven't heard of it before.